# Bigquery Cache Not Working

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed that BigQuery no longer cache the same query even I have chosen to use cache in the GUI (both Alpha and Classic). I didn't edit the query at all, just keep clicking run query button and every time GUI executed the query without using cache results.

It happens to my PHP script as well. Before, it was enable to use cache and came back with results very quick and now it executes the query every time even the same query has been executed minutes ago. I can confirm the behaviour in the logs.

I am wondering if there is anything changed in the last few weeks? Or some kind of account level settings control this? Because it was working fine for me.

Comment: What is the query? Try to provide as much relevant information as possible when asking for help.

Comment: Like Elliot said, provide the query. Also screenshots, description about the table e.g. is it a streaming table. Anything really to help us understand!

Comment: Don't think the queries matters because they all behave like this. Simple query like this:

`SELECT COUNT(PageviewID) FROM project.dataset.pageviews WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2018-07-01")`

And very complex queries they all can't use cache results. Others in Sydney Australia also confirmed the same issue.

Comment: The project location is not in Sydney GCP, to clarify.

Comment: Are you streaming to the table?

Comment: Yes, streaming to the tables. But it worked before with streaming.

Comment: We can verify this has just started occurring. Our tables are streaming using partition time. The CURRENT_DATE() and non-deterministic queries were known previously to not cache (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67518091), however we’ve written code specifically to avoid this issue by replacing these. This fix no longer works, all queries now do not cache, we can verify in the interface and via code. An example:

    
`SELECT Path FROM 'sajaricom.XXXX.stats' WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2018-01-01") LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [official docs here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#query-caching) cache is disable when:

> ...any of the tables referenced by the query have recently received
>   streaming inserts...

Even if you are streaming to one partition, and then querying to another, this will invalidate caching functionality for the whole table. There is this [feature request opened](https://issuetracker.google.com/109634903) where it is requested to be able to hit cache when doing streaming inserts to one partition but querying a different partition.

EDIT***:

After some investigation I've found out that some months ago there was an issue going on which was allowing to hit the cache even streaming inserts were being made. This was not expected behavior, and therefore it got solved in May. I guess this is the change you have experienced and what you are talking about.

Docs have not changed related to this, and they aren't/weren't incorrect. Just the previous behavior was the incorrect one.

Comment: Your answer doesn't cover the case where it was observed working until recently. Either the docs have changed recently or are/were incorrect. Identifying which of those cases is true would be a more useful answer, I think.

Comment: Hi @Trent! Google Cloud Platform Support here. I have edited the answer with some more information I've found about it.

Comment: Hi Victor, our previous days partition don't have a streaming buffer attached, we only stream inserts to the current day partition. We understand hitting today's partition has never cached. You can see my example query in the comment to the OP, the partition queried is 6 months old.

Thanks for the info on the issue in May but the timeline is too far off for these to be related. We have only experienced this issue for the last couple of days.

Comment: @VictorGGl Thanks for the info. But we have been streaming into the table for over a year and it was perfectly fine with caching until recently. So it was a bug for a long time and the May update removed it if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Hi @Trent, whenever you are doing streaming inserts to any partition of a table, it invalidates hitting the cache for the whole table (all partitions in the table). There is a public Issue tracker where I requested to be able to hit the cache in one partition when you are streaming to a different partition. You can star it to follow its progress (https://issuetracker.google.com/109634903). If  at some point you have been able to hit the cache meanwhile you were doing streaming inserts  to the table, this was not expected.

Comment: Hi @ChaomingLi, Yes. The  right behavior is that when streaming to a table the cache is invalidated. During long time (I'm sorry I cannot be any accurate in here) this was not working properly, and even if you were streaming to a table the cache was working. This was not intended, and therefore at the beginning of May this got solved. So yes, since May caching functionality is working again as per documentation in my answer.